# PayPal discount coupon integration

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am working on a simple discount coupon input for a PayPal checkout page.

The simple coupon input that i am trying to integrate should work only when there is ONE item in the cart and the coupon should be useable only ONCE.

```
> <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"
> onsubmit="this.target = 'paypal'; return ReadForm (this);"> <input
> type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> <input type="hidden"
> name="add" value="1" /> <input type="hidden" name="business"
> value="email here" /> <input type="hidden" name="item_name"
> value="1 Item" /> <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50.00" />
> <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" /> <input
> type="hidden" name="baseamt" value="50.00" /> <input type="hidden"
> name="basedes" value="1 Item" /> <input type="text" size="10"
> name="coupcode"; /> <input type="button" value="Check code"
> onclick="coupval =this.form.coupcode.value;  ChkCoup();" /> <input
> type="image" id="xx"
> src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"
> border="0" name="submit" onclick="CalculateOrder(this.form)"
> alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"> <img alt=""
> border="0"
> src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
> width="1" height="1"> </form>
> 
> <script type="text/javascript" src="discount.js"></script>
```

**My question: is there an easy way to be able to integrate a coupon discount input to PayPal advanced Payment?**

Answer (score 0):

Easy?  Depends on your development skill level.  This would require tying the coupon into your own application's local shopping cart.  Everything would be calculated accordingly based on their items, shipping, tax, discounts applied, etc.  Once you have those final totals you would pass them into Payments Advanced accordingly.

What you have here, though, doesn't look like Advanced.  This just looks like a PayPal Standard HTML form.  PayPal Advanced works with API calls in combination with an iframe on your site.  What you're doing here is just generating basic HTML.

The same is true, though.  You would calculate everything in your own cart, and then populate the amount parameters in this HTML form accordingly.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a coupon related question here : tinyurl.com/ojokhs5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issue.i have a solution.It may also useful to you.

If your  using the discount in amount means :

```
  <input type="hidden" value=".50" name="discount_amount">
  <input type="hidden" value=".50" name="discount_amount2">
```

If your using the discount in percentage or rate means:

```
  <input type="hidden" value="50" name="discount_rate">
  <input type="hidden" value="50" name="discount_rate2">
```